# Regex that captures only some text between two words

Tags: node.js, regex

I'm looking for a single regex written for nodejs that can capture only text in lines that start with PASS! or FAIL! and appears between two specific words. Example:

```
INFO! this line shouldn't be captured because it's before section121
[section120] section title1
Some noise
PASS! this line shouldn't captured either because it's before section121
[section121] section title2
more noise
FAIL! match1
a warning we wish to skip
more warnings
PASS! match2
FAIL! match3
[section122] section title3
noise
PASS! this shouldn't be captured because it appears after section122
```

The expected captures for this input are:

```
match1
match2
match3
```

Can this be achieved using a single regex? If not, an explanation why would also be accepted as an answer.

I tried writing several different regexes, but always ended up capturing only the last line (match3):

`section121\][\s\S]*(?:PASS!|FAIL!)([\s\S]*)\[section122`

Comment: Why don't you want to match `FAIL! match1` Is there any logic to `a warning we wish to skip` And with "between 2 words", do you mean between `section120` and the next possible occurrence?

Comment: No, in JS, you will need to run two regexps. In PCRE/Java/Boost/ICU, you could use something like https://regex101.com/r/DkAdOj/1

Comment: In JS you can use `(?<=^\[section121].*(?:\n(?!\[section\d+]).*)*\n(?:PASS|FAIL)!).*` but that will still match `match1` https://regex101.com/r/38ALPh/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird sorry it was an editing error (i put match1 in the same line with ```). i fixed it now. i do want match1. the logic to warning and noise is negative - they do not start with FAIL! or PASS! I mean between the words section121 and section122

Comment: @Thefourthbird that's exactly what i want! can you please provide an answer with explanation so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With JavaScript the support of a [lookbehind assertion](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind), you can use:

```
(?<=^\[section121].*(?:\n(?!\[section\d+]).*)*\n(?:PASS|FAIL)!).*
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind

  - `^` Start of string
  - `\[section121].*` Match `[section121]` and the rest of the line
  - `(?:\n(?!\[section\d+]).*)*` Match a newline, and repeat matching all lines that do not start with `[section` 1+ digits and `]`
  - `\n(?:PASS|FAIL)!` Match a newline and either `PASS!` or `FAIL!`
- `)` Close the lookbehind
- `.*` Match the rest of the line (optionally match any character except newlines)

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/lzgFNo/1)

```js
const regex = /(?<=^\[section121].*(?:\n(?!\[section\d+]).*)*\n(?:PASS|FAIL)!).*/gm;

const s = `INFO! this line shouldn't be captured because it's before section121
[section120] section title1
Some noise
PASS! this line shouldn't captured either because it's before section121
[section121] section title2
more noise
FAIL! match1
a warning we wish to skip
more warnings
PASS! match2
FAIL! match3
[section122] section title3
noise
PASS! this shouldn't be captured because it appears after section122`;

console.log(s.match(regex));
```

An alternative without the support for a lookbehind in 2 steps:

```js
const regex = /\[section121].*(?:\n(?!\[section\d+]|(?:PASS|FAIL)!).*)*\n(?:PASS|FAIL)!.*(?:\n(?!\[section\d+]).*)*/;
const s = `INFO! this line shouldn't be captured because it's before section121
[section120] section title1
Some noise
PASS! this line shouldn't captured either because it's before section121
[section121] section title2
more noise
FAIL! match1
a warning we wish to skip
more warnings
PASS! match2
FAIL! match3
[section122] section title3
noise
PASS! this shouldn't be captured because it appears after section122`;

const res = s.match(regex);
if (res) {
  console.log(Array.from(res[0].matchAll(/^(?:PASS|FAIL)!(.*)/mg), m => m[1]))
}
```